# Laravel : unsigned with index

Tags: laravel, migration

I want to create a foreign key in the review table. Here is my table structure.

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('reviews', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete(
            'cascade'
        );
        $table->string('customer');
        $table->text('review');
        $table->integer('star');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Now my question is: I do not understand the below statements.

```
$table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->index();
```

I do not want to execute this query without understanding this particular statement.
What does `unsigned()->index()` mean in laravel?

I read the official documentation of laravel for several times. They tell that unsigned() means `Set INTEGER to UNSIGNED`. Lacking limitation of mine. I do not understand a single piece of the word that they tell about this particular query. Please explain in simple words if you can.
Another question: If I do not declare `unsigned()->index()` with the `integer('product_id')` then what is to be the problem? Thank you in advance for your presence.

Comment: Unsigned type can be used to permit only nonnegative numbers in a column or when you need a larger upper numeric range for the column. For example, if an **INT** column is **UNSIGNED**, the size of the column's range is the same but its endpoints shift from **-2147483648** and **2147483647** up to **0** and **4294967295**.

Comment: A database **index** is a data structure that improves the speed of operations in a table. Indexes can be created using one or more columns. Here you dont need to define  the column as a `index()` because `product_id` is a foreign key, and a foreign key is indedex by default

Comment: Thank you, Sir. I understand from your clarifications. Thank you again.